# Looking for a desktop pop-up app I can use for Science Fiction/Fantasy

Tags: support, notifier

I joined Science Fiction/Fantasy (SFF) in 2011. For many years I had an app running - an app I found on the site - that would create a pop-up whenever a *Harry Potter* question was asked. It would pop up on my desktop, notifying me immediately that a new HP question had been posted. It didn't require an RSS reader or that I look through my email. It just popped up on top of whatever I was working on, on my computer screen. When I got a new computer, I went to install the pop-up app, but I couldn't find it, and I haven't been able to find it since.

I want to be clear that I am looking for a desktop pop-up app, not an RSS or email app. **Is there any pop-up program I can use for SFF questions available that you know of? If so, where would I find it?**

Comment: If it has been posted here, it probably has the [tag:notifier] tag; that'd mean you'd have to check 30 questions. Depending on how good your memory is, that might work...

Comment: @Glorfindel - Thanks! I'll see if I can find a pop-up app using the notifier tag. I'm pretty sure I would be able to recognize the app if it's still available.  :)